# Tablesorter filter HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jquery plugin paired with this great tablesorter [filter](http://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter/tree/master) plugin.

One of the columns consists only of `<img... title="">` tags. When I try to filter it finds nothing. How can I filter by the text in the title attribute?

Interestingly the sort function works great.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the filter plugin to work ([broken demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1435/))... it has a javascript error every time I tried to search. So, I will give you a solution that uses my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) instead:

What was missing is that a custom parser for the image needs to be used. This is actually built into the forked version; but since the image text could be added to numerous places (e.g. `title`, `alt`, etc), there is a [`imgAttr` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#imgattr) which can be set to the desired attribute ([here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/679/))

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        imgAttr: 'title',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
    });
});
```

If you don't want a filter for each column, then check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html) which shows how to add an external "all" column search input.